# Wordpress menu behaviour on browser / resolution change

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I am trying to change our website ( [www.enyx.sk](http://www.enyx.sk) ) from a floating responsive theme, to achieve a static width, which would address also lower resolution tablets and monitors.

The problem I having is with the menu items in the top navigation. The parent div itself is absolutely positioned but, since they are generated and need to be next to each other, the items are positioned relatively. Hovewer this causes a problem, when I try to resize my browser, or I check the resolution on the Nexus 7 ---> [here](https://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http://enyx.sk&w=603&h=966&a=23&s=1)

then the menu items appear one under another, to fill the sreen.

What I want to achieve is that they stay in one place like the "mozaic" under the menu, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a look at your basic.css (should be within the ubermenu-plugin). Almost all widths there are given in percent.

On line 758 you can find:

```
#megaMenu.megaResponsive ul.megaMenu > li { width: 100% }
```

Furthermore on line 862 there is:

```
#megaMenu.megaResponsive ul.megaMenu > li { width:50% }
```

Delete both.

At least there is the following code in line 81:

```
#megaMenu.megaMenuHorizontal ul.megaMenu { width: 100% }
```

Change it to a fixed width (e.g. 1140px). Now everything should work in a correct way.

If you use Firefox you can use the add-on Firebug, which is a big help looking for that kind of stuff.

Comment: I just had a second look to your sites' construction. There are a lot of css snippets in the head and it's hard to keep track of the whole thing. ;)

I just tried your page on my Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 and everything is fine, but on my iPhone it has a completely different responsive view. It seems like there is a media query somewhere in your CSS, which focusses on devices, so the desktop won't show it, but your nexus (and my iphone). I couldn't find it right now, but I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you @Fabi, I am currently done with most of the things. The only one thing left, when I open the desktop site on my phone (res. of 480x800) the post appear cropped from the right and I can't figure out what is causing it. I was trying to modify the media querys which are in the header but couldn't find the problem. It would be easier if I could check the source code of the page on the phone, unfortunately I can not. Sorry for the messy CSS, I am customizing a theme, and I am pretty new to CSS also :).